# AkkaNet deprecated scheduler - how to replace it?

Tags: akka.net

I have a  method:

```
 Context.System.Scheduler.Schedule(
              TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 
              TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 
              Self, 
              message);
```

I am getting that this is deprecated and I should use

```
Context.SelfTellRepeatedly()
```

But there is no method like that - or maybe I am missing something?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're correct, it looks like this method is missing.  I don't know if this is deliberate or not, it may be that the Obsolete message is out of date. Probably worth raising it as issue for the maintainers.

However, hopefully the message you're seeing is this one.

```
[Obsolete("Use ScheduleTellRepeatedly() or Context.SelfTellRepeatedly() instead.
This method will be removed in future versions.")]
public static void Schedule(this IScheduler scheduler, 
       TimeSpan initialDelay, TimeSpan interval, IActorRef receiver, object message)
```

The correct replacement would be the `Scheduler.ScheduleTellRepeatedly()` method, which does exist.